# Remove Invalid data from VarChar column

Tags: sql, types

I have a database with a column of VarChar type, within which are integers (which I want to keep) and miscellaneous non-numeric values (which I want to remove).  If I alter the table and add a new integer column, how can I copy only the integers into the new integer column?

Answer (score 5):

I'd give this a shot (will work with MSSQL, not sure about other database systems)...

```
update MyTable
set    MyNewIntField = cast(MyOldVarcharField as int)
where  isnumeric(MyOldVarcharField) = 1
```

Comment: As long as you don't mind truncating the floats and including them, then this method works fine.

Answer (score 1):

this should do it for you if you are running MS SQL:

```
update mytable set new_column = old_column where isnumeric(old_column) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You will fail out if you end up trying to put decimal data into the integer column.

You have 2 choices here

you could only accept data if it is whole numbers:

```
 update [table]
 set [integer column] = [varchar column]
 where isnumeric([varchar column])=1 and ([varchar column] not like '%.%')
```

or you could round or truncate the decimals

```
--truncate
 update [table]
 set [integer column] = floor(cast([varchar column] as float))
 where isnumeric([varchar column])=1
 --round
 update [table]
 set [integer column] = round(cast([varchar column] as float),0)
 where isnumeric([varchar column])=1
```